# Grant is set to NO after running GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ip_address'

Tags: mysql-5.5

I'm trying to grant all privileges to a root user when accessing from external IP using the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ip_address';
```

However the GRANT permission is sill set to NO.

**update**
I can update GRANT permission manually by running the command below, but I'd still like to know why it's not set when using 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `Grant_priv`='Y' WHERE `Host`='ip_address' and`User`='root';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ip_address' identified by 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and don't forget to :

```
Flush privileges;
```